# C++ why is my pointer taking me to some weird location as soon as I call a->val?

Tags: c++

I'm working through a LeetCode problem with two linked lists that need to be added up.

It looks like my code is correctly generating a new list, with the expected nodes 7, and 9, followed by null, yet when I try to print out the results I'm running into an issue. I can see that the value of a->val is 7, but as soon as I get to the cout << a->val; line, it turns into another value.
[image]

[image]

Why is this happening?

```
using namespace std;



struct ListNode {
    int val;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
    ListNode(int x, ListNode* next) : val(x), next(next) {}
};



ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode ans;
    ListNode* ptr = &ans;
    int carry = 0;

    while (l1 || l2) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;

        if (l1) {
            a = l1->val;
            l1 = l1->next;
        }

        if (l2) {
            b = l2->val;
            l2 = l2->next;
        }

        ptr->val = (a + b) % 10 + carry;
        carry = (a + b) / 10;

        if (l1 || l2) {
            ptr->next = new ListNode();
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }

    return &ans;
}

int main()
{
    ListNode b(2);
    ListNode c(7);

    ListNode l1(2, &b);
    ListNode l2(5, &c);

    ListNode* a = addTwoNumbers(&l1, &l2);

    while (a) {
        cout << a->val;
        a = a->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ans` is allocated on the stack, locally. As soon as you return from `addTwoNumbers`, there is no guarantee the data is still there, i.e. it's undefined behavior. GCC [warns about it](https://godbolt.org/z/a8rxqf):

```
<source>: In function 'ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode*, ListNode*)':
<source>:45:12: warning: address of local variable 'ans' returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]
   45 |     return &ans;
      |            ^~~~
<source>:18:14: note: declared here
   18 |     ListNode ans;
      |              ^~~
```

So, you must declare `ans` on the heap, using `new`:

```cpp
ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
    ListNode* ans = new ListNode();
    ListNode* ptr = ans;

// ...

    return ans;
}
```

[It now runs](https://godbolt.org/z/1sPxjE) and outputs a result.

However, as the other answer has pointed out, you're leaking memory. While it probably won't be a problem for a LeetCode problem, it's a problem for real-life code. Using an smart pointer, such as [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), or doing your own [**RAII**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) wrapper, would be preferable solutions over calling `delete` for each pointer on the list.

Comment: Note that making a list out of unique pointers restricts the maximum size of the list. If `ListNode`s can  destroy each other can get a recursive chain of `ListNode` destructor calls that will exhaust the automatic storage (AKA Stack Overflow) and you're right back to Undefined Behaviour. Use with caution.

Answer (score 4):

Your issue is right here:

```
return &ans;
```

You're returning a pointer to the `ListNode`, `ans`. But the second that function ends, `ans` is destroyed. So you now have a pointer pointing to memory you don't own. And thus, undefined behavior.

For this to work, you'll need to dynamically allocate memory, so that it won't be deallocated automatically when `ans` goes out of scope. Even better would be to make a `List` class that handles all of your memory management so you don't have to think about it, instead of trying to make a list the c-style way here with just basically a `Node` struct.